# Is there a TzScan API to find the number of Tezos Node?

Tags: baker, api, javascript

I'm looking for an API to get the number of Tezos Node or the number of Bakers.

Answer (score 1):

It's on the site. Just go tzscan and click API, or here you go https://tzscan.io/api

Comment: I already looked on https://tzscan.io/api but didn't find what I request for.
Is it this one ? 
https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/nb_heads

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically?

Comment: I want to show on my website the number of baker and delegator using an API request.